# Consulta de datos a dos tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

tengo una duda al respecto de como consultar datos de dos tablas para obtener el resultado que deseo, tengo dos tablas una llamada "Ferias" y otra llamada "Atracciones", en esta última se registran aquellas que han sido visitadas, sin embargo en la consulta que requiero hacer necesito obtener lo siguiente:

- El ID de la feria
- El Nombre de la feria
- El número total de atracciones correspondientes a esa feria
- El número de atracciones que ya han sido visitados

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT F.NombreFeria, COUNT(*) as Total_Atracciones
FROM Ferias F
INNER JOIN Atracciones A ON F.ID_Feria = A.FK_IDFeria
GROUP BY (F.NombreFeria)
```

pero solo logro que me traiga las ferias con el total de atracciones de cada una:

NombreFeria | Total_Atracciones

Feria México  | 3

Feria USA     | 2

Feria Canadá  | 1

Anexo una imagen del resultado que requiero con las dos tablas involucradas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por el comentario, ya he editado la pregunta con lo poco o mucho que había hecho, le agradezco por la observación que tenga buen día.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usa la siguiente sintaxis en tu consulta.

Unes ambas tablar con **INNER JOIN** y el campo en común **ID_FERIA-FK_IDFERIA**, agrupamos los campos de feria con **GROUP BY**, y sumamos la cantidad de coincidencias en B.ID_ATRACCIONES con **COUNT**, en el caso de las visitas vemos la suma de los valores con **SUM**.

```
SELECT
A.ID_FERIA, A.NOMBRE_FERIA, COUNT(B.ID_ATRACCIONES), SUM(B.ESTATUS_VISITADO)
FROM FERIAS A
INNER JOIN ATRACCIONES B ON A.ID_FERIA = B.FK_IDFERIA
GROUP BY A.ID_FERIA, A.NOMBRE_FERIA
```

Comment: En general tratamos de que en los ejercicios, quien pregunta demuestre que ha intentado algo. Tu respuesta es correcta, aunque tampoco explica nada al respecto.